# magpierss return garbage text from utf-8 xml after parsing

Tags: php, xml, encoding, magpie

I have been using MagpieRSS to get feed from an xml file.XML file is in UTF-8 character encoding (`language = 'ja,jp'`).

But after parsing the xml, Magpie returns garbage string not japanese characters.

How do I tell Magpie to return UTF-8 format to get the right japanese characters i need?

Comment: `language = 'ja,jp'` *must **not** mnean* that the file is in UTF-8 character encoding . If you add the code and the URL of the RSS feed, I think your question will become more clear.

Comment: I got the answer. you can set magpierss encoding by changing `MAGPIE_OUTPUT_ENCODING` to `UTF-8`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please add this as your answer.